# Laravel 5.5: mesmo campo em várias linhas no seeds

Tags: php, laravel

Como se pode ver no código abaixo, o campo `created_at` é igual em todos, a única coisa que muda é o `nome`. Teria algum forma de escrever o `created_at` apenas uma vez, mas que insira em todas linhas?

```
DB::table('generos')->insert([
            [
                'nome' => 'Ação',
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
            [
                'nome' => 'Comédia',
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
            [
                'nome' => 'Terror',
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
            [
                'nome' => 'Policial',
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
            [
                'nome' => 'Fantasia',
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Já pensou em definir no banco o campo `created_at` como `default` para `now()`? desta maneira você não precisaria passar nenhum valor pois o `sgbd` irá automaticamente definir aquele campo como padrão para `now`

Comment: Não me liguei em fazer isso hahaha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão no Laravel `created_at` é inserido automaticamente, salvo em casos que você esteja usando um Model, é claro.

Em caso de usar o método `insert`, a inserção precisa ser manual.

Se você quer inserir o `created_at` apenas uma vez como comentado , apenas refatorando o código completamente:

```
$now = new DateTime;

$generos = array_map(function ($genero) use ($now) {

    return ['nome' => $genero, 'created_at' => $now];
}, [
    'Ação',
    'Comédia',
    'Fantasia',
    'Policial',
    'Terror',
]);

DB::table('generos')->insert($generos);
```

Comment: No método `insert` não.

Comment: Valeu @LINQ :p :p

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um array de generos e inserir os objetos em um `foreach`

```
$nomes = array('Ação', 'Comédia', 'Terror');
$generos = [];
$tabela = DB::table('generos')
foreach ($generos as $genero) {
    array_push($generos, ['nome' => $genero, 'created_at' => Carbon::now()]);
}
$tabela->insert($generos);
```

Comment: -1 Assim ele vai executar um `insert` pra cada iteração do `foreach`.

Comment: Verdade @WallaceMaxters, eu editei minha resposta.

Comment: Ao invés de `array_push` você poderia ter usado `$generos[] = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Se o **Generos** tiver um model poderia usar os métodos padrão de `create/save`, eles setam esse campo automaticamente. Assim como o `updated_at`.

Tentou colocar em uma variável e depois só passá-la para o `insert`?

```
$now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
DB::table('generos')->insert([
    [
        'nome' => 'Ação',
        'created_at' => $now,
    ],
    [
        'nome' => 'Comédia',
        'created_at' => $now,
    ],
    [
        'nome' => 'Terror',
        'created_at' => $now,
    ],
    [
        'nome' => 'Policial',
        'created_at' => $now,
    ],
    [
        'nome' => 'Fantasia',
        'created_at' => $now,
    ]
]);
```

Com um array de nomes e um foreach para salva-los:
antes de abrir a classe você adiciona o:

```
use App\Genero;
```

depois de abri-la:

```
public $genero;
public function __construct(Genero $genero){
    $this->genero = $genero;
}

function xyz(){
    $nomes = array('Ação', 'Comédia', 'Terror', 'Policial', 'Fantasia');
    foreach($nomes as $nome){
        $genero = App\Genero::create(['nome' => $nome]); // Se estiver definido no construct vai usar o this:
        $genero = $this->genero->create(['nome' => $nome]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assim funciona, mas eu queria algo que não precisasse escrever o created_at varias vezes. Vou deixar o valor como default mesmo.

Comment: Editei a resposta, se voce tiver um model pode usar as funções padrão, elas setam os valores automaticamente quando vc as chama.

Comment: Vou fazer isso. Outra coisa, a parte do nome nao teria como fazer algo semelhante a isso: 'nome' => ['teste1', 'teste2']. Pois vou repetir sempre o mesmo campo(nome), so vai mudar o valor, acredito que ficaria mais limpo o codigo.

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: @DiegoVieira A tua intenção é não repetir os nomes dos campos, certo?